# Python - scraping files that are in JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping

I'm trying to download files from a VA dataset website with a Python scraper but I'm having trouble figuring out how to parse the JavaScript in the HTML website that appears to contain the files. This is source code for the website (view-source:https://www.data.va.gov/dataset/Air-Force-Veterans-2017-Living-Only/9u8y-zaby). I'm trying to download the ".xlsx" files, which (by just using command+F on my Mac) I think are in JavaScript objects. I've looked around this site and others but haven't been able to figure out how to scrape links from within JavaScript. How should I go about doing this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `.xlsx` means that it's an Excel file.

Comment: @Pointy I realize that and it seems they're not contained in the usual HTML, but rather JavaScript objects

Comment: No, the JavaScript is probably for arranging the download of the `.xlsx` files. The files themselves are probably (almost certainly) separate URLs.

Comment: In fact you can clearly see it if you inspect that `<a>` element; the URL for the download is "https://www.data.va.gov/download/9u8y-zaby/application%2Fvnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"

Comment: Storing `.xlsx` source in JavaScript on a page would be fairly insane, as `.xlsx` files are generally very large.

Comment: @Pointy this is helpful, thanks. How would you find that URL for download in the source code then? I can't seem to find it using command+F and I'm not sure how I would direct a scraper to find it

Comment: That "Download" button has classes "btn", "btn-primary", and "download", so you could look for a combination of those. If you find one or more, you can look at its "href" attribute for the URL.

Answer (score 1):

That website is dynamically generated, you can use selenium to download the desired files

Here is a working code
using `wget`, `selenium` and `webdriver_manager`

This will check for the link and save the `xlsx` file in used-defined directory

```
import time
import wget
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions, FirefoxOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = ChromeOptions()
# try out options
# options.binary_location = '/opt/headless-chromium'
# options.add_argument("--headless")
# options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
# options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
# options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
# options.add_argument('--disable-gpu-sandbox')
# options.add_argument("--single-process")
options.add_argument(
    "user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.54 Safari/537.36")
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])

s = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
# s = Service(GeckoDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)

driver.get('https://www.data.va.gov/dataset/Air-Force-Veterans-2017-Living-Only/9u8y-zaby')
time.sleep(3)

# get the link
download_link = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="app"]/div/div[2]/section/div/div/div[2]/a').get_attribute(
    'href')

# download the file
output_directory = 'data'  # it will download the file to data directory
filename = wget.download(download_link, out=output_directory)

time.sleep(3)
driver.close()
driver.quit()
```